# Is it possible the shattered glass has never been shattered?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

You know we usually say "broken windown" when window has broken, "rotten food" when food has rotten.

Is it possible the shattered glass has never been shattered?

I'm wondering because if God magically makes "shattered glass", but it has just been made, so it has never been shattered. Can we say **God made shattered glass**? Or is it reasonable just to say God made pieces of glass?

Comment: I don't see how 'shattered glass' is any different from your other examples. Either they degraded, or (as some might say re the age of the Earth) god made them to look as though they had degraded.

Comment: This question reminds me of my jeweler, who insists that by definition there does not exist such a thing as "diamond slivers".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think "shattered" implies an act of shattering in the past, so if the glass was created fragmented from the get go the description would not be appropriate.